# sql - retain calculated result in calculated field

Tags: sql-server-2005

certain fields in our database contain calculated functions e.g.

```
select lastname + ', ' + firstname as fullname from contact where contact.id =$contact$
```

when viewing the field the correct data is shown (i assume this is because when you open the record, the calculation is executed). however, the data is not 'stored' to the field, and therefore is null until the record is opened. is it possible to 'store' the result to the field, making it possible to search the data?

many thanks

james

**EDIT**

it is not possible for me to create computed_columns using our software.

the above field is a text feild where either 1) a user can manual type in the required data or 2) the database can generate the answer for you (but only whilst you are looking at the record). i know that if I run the following:

```
Select * from contact where contact.id =$contact$ for xml auto
```

i only get `lastname, firstname` - so i know that the fullname field does not retain its information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using computed columns in sql server, the column is already searchable regardless of whether the calculation result is stored or not.  However, if you would like to make it so that the calculation is not run each time you read the row, you can change that under row properties in your Modify Table GUI.

Comment: Clarification: it's the Design Table GUI, not Modify Table.  Right Click table, select Design, in Designer right click the computed column, select properties, under computed column specification set IsPersisted to true.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `PERSISTED` key word when you create the column

From BOL:

> PERSISTED 
>   Specifies that the SQL Server Database Engine will physically store the computed values in the table, and update the values when any other columns on which the computed column depends are updated. Marking a computed column as PERSISTED lets you create an index on a computed column that is deterministic, but not precise. For more information, see Creating Indexes on Computed Columns. Any computed columns that are used as partitioning columns of a partitioned table must be explicitly marked PERSISTED. computed_column_expression must be deterministic when PERSISTED is specified.

Comment: @Duncan i've been reading up on this. however, due to the restricted access i have user end (i am using proprietary software) i have no access to a table builder. i can alter an existing column however. Would you know how to identify if a column is indeed a computed_coloumn through a xml auto? and/or is it possible to change an extisting column to persisted?

Comment: @James - when you say "through a xml auto", I assume you mean you are querying the table "for xml auto". If you have the ability to query the system tables, you could use `select name, is_computed
from sys.columns 
where object_id=object_id(<table_name>)`. I will look into how you can identify if it is persisted as well.

Comment: @Duncan thanks for the suggestion (apologise i didnt make it obvious enough) - i ran through your coding, and it returned:
`<SYS.COLUMNS NAME="POANextDue" IS_COMPUTED="0"/>`
so i guess this field isn't a computed column. Any ideas where to next take this? Thanks

Comment: @James - I don't think you can alter the persistence of a column once it has been created. The only way to achieve this would be to drop the existing column and redefine it - you could use `select * from syscomments where id=object_id(<table_name>)` to find out how the column is defined. You need to go to your DBA (if you have one) though to make the change correctly.

Comment: @Duncan - ran a `select * from syscomments where id=object_id(<table_name>)` between my last comment and yours - i have editted the question to reflect the findings. Do you have any idea what the other values control?

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106(v=SQL.90).aspx] Alas none of them specify whether the column is a persisted computed column.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the way computed columns work in SQL Server, so I suspect this is something your client application is doing. How are you looking at the data when the value is computed correctly? Does it work when you view the data in SSMS?

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=SQL.90).aspx to see how to create computed columns properly.

eg.

```
create table TestTable
    (a int,
    b int,
    c as a + b)

insert into TestTable (a,b)
values (1,2)

select * from TestTable
where c = 3
```

This query is based on the computed column and it returns the row that's been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the PERSISTED option on a column when you use CREATE TABLE e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE test (col_a INT, col_b INT, col_c AS col_A * col_B PERSISTED)
```